# Calling a non-static method from outside the class

Tags: java, android

I often have to deal with this kind an error when programming in Java on Android.
For example I have a class where I set a flag.

```
public class ViewActivity extends Activity {  
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    ...
}
```

In another class I want to reset the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

```
class DrawOnTop extends View {
...
if (condition) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

but this doesn't work, since I get "The method getWindow is undefined for the type DrawOnTop".

So I try to define a clearFlags method in ViewActivity class

```
void clearFlags() {
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

and to call it from the DrawOnTop class:

```
    if (condition) {
        ViewActivity.clearFlags();
    }
```

This doesn't work as well: I get "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method clearFlags() from the type ViewActivity".
Well, let's make it static then.

```
static void clearFlags() {
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

and then I get "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getWindow from the type Activity"

How could I execute such a statement?

Comment: You need a reference to your *actual* `ViewActivity` instance, and use *that* from inside `DrawOnTop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DrawOnTop class is nested within the ViewActivity you can create a local Context variable and use it to call the getWindow(). If that's not the case then create a receiver in your activity class then from DawOnTop send an intent with your trigger to do whatever the job is. Do not instantiate your activity class, bad idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can send `getWindow()` as parameter into `clearFlags` method.
Call `clearFlags(Window window)` from your activity: `WindowHelper.getInstance().clearFlags(getWindow());`

Helper class:

```
public class WindowHelper {

    public static final WindowHelper instance = new WindowHelper();

    public static WindowHelper getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void clearFlags(Window window) {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement the solutions suggested by Aksaçlı and this turned out to be very simple:

In the ViewActivity class DrawonTop is called this way:
`mDrawOnTop = new DrawOnTop(this);`

The constructor of the second class contains this:

```
public DrawOnTop(Context context) {
            super(context);
```

Therefore `ViewActivity.clearFlags();` has simply to be rewritten as `((ViewActivity)getContext()).clearFlags();`

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should refer to an initialised object in your static method. So instead of:

```
void clearFlags() {
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

you should create a static instance variable of your window:

```
private static staticWindowInstance;

void clearFlags() {
getStaticWindowInstance().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

For more information, you should check out the [Singleton design pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html).

Comment: Statics are not the answer.